# Error when building QMYSQL Plugin on Windows

Tags: qt

I receive an error when I try to build the QMYSQL plugin for Windows 10.

I have installed Qt 5.12.1 and the path to sql drivers is `c:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers` and the path to the library files is `c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib`.

I opened a cmd window and typed the folowing:
`c:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/" mysql.pro`

Comment: what is the complete error message?

Comment: 'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I watched many tutorials on youtube and messages on forums, I am trying for two days to build the QMYSQL driver, but I do not succeed.

Comment: search inside the `c:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1` folder for the qmake.exe executable and then use its full path: `c:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers> /path/of/qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/"`

Comment: I know it does not work for you, you do not have to point it out to me, try what you say.

Comment: then add `"C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin"` to the environment variables

Comment: The path of qmake.exe is "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin", so the full path should look something like this:  c:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers>C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/mingw73_64/bin/qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/     , and I think is the good path but there is something to add

Comment: This is what I get after run the above command :   Usage: C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/mingw73_64/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project

Comment: see this: https://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

Comment: I've already seen that tutorial, unfortunately is out of date

Answer (score 0):

Now it's work for Qt 5.14.2 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit) on Windows7x64
Since building according official tutorial https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql not work for me, I found a work-around way(https://dev.to/f1r361rd/how-i-build-a-mysql-plugin-for-qt5-windows-mingw32-2kim):

1. Download MySql MySQL Server 5.1 sources
2. In file
   D:\QT\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql\mysql.pro
   Comment the line QMAKE_USE += mysql
3. Adding Library path and Include path.
   Add the following to mysql.pro at end

   LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/lib/opt/libmysql.lib'
   -llibmysql
   INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1/include'
   DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1/include/mysql.h'
4. Execute sequence commands: qmake -> nmake -> nmake install